# WordPress URL Rewrite for dynamic and customized URL

Tags: categories, permalinks, url-rewriting, query-string

I'm working on a website in WordPress where I have to show AP News from external Database and not from the WordPress DB.

I have created few shortcodes for this, which are working absolutely fine. I have created a separate page to show news details called "details".

Here is my URL.

> http://www.example.com/news/details?ID=f50ccf32a5cd4169af6522e8903d0207&type=world&subtype=africa

Where, News = Category, Details = WP Page and ID = id of the News

In specific requirement I need to have a URL like shown Below.

> http://www.example.com/news/world/f50ccf32a5cd4169af6522e8903d0207/Pistorius-investigators-meet-Apple-over-iPhone.html

If we go for above mentioned URL, WordPress will try to find post with name "pistorius-investigators-meet-apple-over-iphone" in our WordPress site, which really does not exist. We fetch it from an external database.

Is there any way I can manipulate my URL to SEO friendly URL ?